# CreateProcessAsUser doesn't run the application

Tags: windows, api, vb6

I would like to run my setup "d:\myapp_setup_update.exe", and since I run it from a service, I am trying to use CreateProcessAsUsers.

However, I think I might have gotten the syntax wrong.
Before running this code, I have made sure that the path exists and that hToken isn't 0.

This is my current approach.

Does anybody spot any error?
I'm not even sure about the API declaration. MSDN uses longs in some samples, then again strings. Really strange.

Thank you very much for the help!

```
Private Declare Function CreateProcessAsUser Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        Alias "CreateProcessAsUserA" _
        (ByVal hToken As Long, _
        ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
        ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
        ByVal lpProcessAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
        ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
        ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, _
        ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, _
        lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
        lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Function pDoIt(ByVal hToken As Long) As Boolean

    Dim sChildProcName$
    sChildProcName = "d:\myapp_setup_update.exe"

    Dim tProcessInfo As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim tStartupinfo As STARTUPINFO
    tStartupinfo.cb = Len(tStartupinfo)

    Dim bChildProcStarted As Boolean
    bChildProcStarted = CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, sChildProcName, vbNullString, 0&, 0&, 0, 0&, 0, vbNullString, tStartupInfo, tProcessInfo)

    'GetLastError always returns 0... strange

    pDoIt = bChildProcStarted

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The application that I want to run should be stated as the "lpCommandLine" arg.